# Flexray Communication Fault

Tags: autosar

How the communication fault (bus-off) is achieved in flex ray Network?

I have done following things:
1) Short BP to BM Pin of flexray, for bus-off.
2) after shorting the pins, error frames are generated & I am able to see the frames over trace window.
3) but still there is transmission of frames from the actual ECU's
4) as per flexray internal states, there is no bus-off, but there are states like NORMAL ACTIVE, NORMAL PASSIVE etc.

When Flexray communication loss fault is generated, say for 11sec, I am setting particular DTC code.

Comment: Is anybody answer above questions??

Comment: Also There is some information from vector is available:There can be Sync loss DEM event even before the timer T3 expires because during the start up FrSM send request (to lower layer module) to be ONLINE 
but the hardware is still in PASSIVE instead of transition state, this indicates FrSM that there is some problem and it will trigger the DEM event.
If the hardware is in transition state then it will wait for timer T3 to expire and then cause a DEM event.